# Thread local storage mixing c++ and .net

Tags: c#, c++, thread-local-storage

I have a C# code calling function `f()` in C++ dll.

The c# code is calling `f()` from several threads. `f()` contains static variable defined as thread local storage ( using `boost::thread_specific_ptr`).

The C++ dll is compiled with visual studio 2012. There seem to be wierd crashes while running the code. 
**Is it safe to use the local storage in C++ while the thread is created in C# ?**

Comment: Hi @Chanoch. Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help people answer your question I suggest adding a minimal code example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

**It seems that using local storage on C++ DLL for a thread created in C# is not a problem**.

Tried on Win7 VS2012, seems to work (crashes were due to other bugs).